# Trying to make lollipop plots (aka comb plots) in basic PGF, but how to draw vertical line so that it ends at the plot's y=0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to create a new TikZ visualizer for lollipop plots, aka comb plots. I know that I could use pgfplots, but I'm trying to learn the insides of TikZ/PGF. I adapted the example in the manual (Section 83.4) and came up with this (IMHO minimal, but still fairly large) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\pgfooclass{lollipop visualizer}
{
  % Stores the name of the visualizer. This is needed for filtering
  % and configuration
  \attribute name;
  
  % The constructor. Just setup the attribute.
  \method lollipop visualizer(#1) { \pgfooset{name}{#1} }
  
  % Connect to visualize signal.
  \method default connects() {
    \pgfoothis.get handle(\me)
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/data visualization/obj}.connect(\me,visualize,visualize datapoint signal)
  }

  % This method is invoked for each data point. It checks whether the
  % data point belongs to the correct visualizer and, if so, calls the
  % macro \dovisualization to do the actual visualization.
  \method visualize() {
    \pgfdvfilterpassedtrue
    \pgfdvnamedvisualizerfilter
    \ifpgfdvfilterpassed
      \dovisualization
    \fi
  }
}

\newdimen\lastx

\def\dovisualization{
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/\pgfoovalueof{name}/execute at begin}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointdvdatapoint}{1pt}
  \pgfextractx{\lastx}{\pgfpointdvdatapoint}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\lastx}{0cm}}
  % \pgfusepath is done by |execute at end|
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/\pgfoovalueof{name}/execute at end}
}

\tikzdatavisualizationset{
  visualize as lollipop/.style={
    new object={
      when=after survey,
      store=/tikz/data visualization/visualizers/#1,
      class=lollipop visualizer,
      arg1=#1
    },
    new visualizer={#1}{%
      color=visualizer color,
      % a color setup by the style sheet
      every path/.style={fill,draw}, % fill and draw the circle by default,
    }{}, % let's ignore legends in this example
    /data point/set=#1
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [
  scientific axes,
  visualize as lollipop/.list={a},
  style sheet=strong colors]
data [set=a, format=function] {
  var x : interval [-7:7] samples 29;
  func y = sin(\value x r);
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Running this example gives:

[image: Incorrect lollipop (or comb) plot due to vertical stems being too long]

This is obviously wrong since the lollipop stems should only go to the plot's y=0, instead they go to the lower edge of the image (the image's y=0). And it's clear why: the `\dovisualization` macro has

```
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\lastx}{0cm}}
```

and so the line will extend to the *image's* y=0. But how do I get the correct image y value where the *plot* has y=0?

Comment: Its the x ticks in the same lines of the plots. Try to make plots lines a larger width...

Comment: No, what I meant was that the stems for those points where y<0 should go up, not down. For example, the point at x=4 should have its stem go up.